How to sum with respect to partitions
I would like to know how to program this type of sums, with the first two values whatever I want $S_{k}(0)=m$ and $S_{k}(1)=t$, and for n>0:
$$S_{k}(n+1)= \sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}+\cdots +r_{k}=n}S_{k}(r_{1})\cdot S_{k}(r_{2})\cdots S_{k}(r_{k})$$
(I am considering $r_{i}\geq 0$) For example $k=2$, $m=1$ and $t=1$. I get $S_{2}(0)=1$, $S_{2}(1)=1$, and
$$S_{2}(n+1)= \sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}=n}S_{2}(r_{1})\cdot S_{2}(r_{2})$$
Where this sequence generates the Catalan numbers. How can I write this in Mathematica?

This isn't very performant, but maybe it'll get you started. I'd start by defining a helper function to create the partitions.
SuperIntegerPartitions[n_Integer, k_Integer] := 
  Catenate[
    Permutations /@ 
      (PadRight[#, k] & /@ Catenate[Table[IntegerPartitions[n, {i}], {i, 1, k}]])]

Then your summation could be written like this:
SumS[k_Integer][n_Integer] := 
  Total[Times @@@ Map[SumS[k], SuperIntegerPartitions[n - 1, k], {-1}]]

For your k=2 case...
SumS[2][0] = 1;
SumS[2][1] = 1;

Array[SumS[2], 10, 0]
(* {1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862} *)

Check...
Array[CatalanNumber, 10, 0]
(* {1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862} *)


Thanks, this is more than enough for what I was looking for : )
